# What is the "GeoIP database for Tor" update needed for?

Tags: apt, updates, tor

Today the system asked me to download and install a GeoIP database update for Tor, and I don't know what it is and why it's necessary. I have Tor Browser installed on my PC (with Ubuntu 16.04) but I usually updated it directly from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to tell Tor to use country as a filter for various things. From [the manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en):

> #### ExcludeNodes node,node,…
>
> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes, and address patterns
>   of nodes to avoid when building a circuit. Country codes are 2-letter
>   ISO3166 codes, and must be wrapped in braces; [...]
>
> Country codes are case-insensitive. The code "{??}" refers to nodes
>   whose country can’t be identified. No country code, including {??},
>   works if no GeoIPFile can be loaded. See also the GeoIPExcludeUnknown
>   option below.
>
> #### ExcludeExitNodes node,node,…
>
> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes, and address patterns
>   of nodes to never use when picking an exit node [...]
>
> #### ExitNodes node,node,…
>
> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes [...]

For this to work, a database of IP-to-country mappings is needed, which is the GeoIP database.

If the GeoIP database is being updated by apt, then you must have installed Tor using apt at some point. Tor Browser should include its own GeoIP database. If you're not using the system (apt) Tor, then uninstall it and the GeoIP database package.